# React component Input validation (useState()) one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a validation (integer > 0) on an Input (React component). It has an `onChange={onChangeHandle}` and uses `useState()`. Goal is to show error and disable the Submit button if validation fails. Problem is that the validation is one step behind:

Example:

- Initial value 0 - no validation
- Type "1" - `false` => shows error, button disabled (it should be `true` here)
- Add another "1", so "11" - `true` => error hides, button enabled

Code is as follows:

```
const onChangeHandle = e => {
const isMileageValid = Number.isInteger(Number(mileage)) && Number(mileage) > 0;
if (!isMileageValid){
    setErrorMessage(gettext('You must enter a valid mileage'));
}
else {
    setErrorMessage(null);
}
setMileage(e.target.value);
setDisableConfirmButton(!isMileageValid);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your order of operations. In your example, you create a variable named `isMileageValid` (line 2) which depends on `mileage`. However, you have not set the content of `mileage` using `setMileage()` yet, because you invoke this afterwards (line 6)

Instead, you can get the value from the function (`e.target.value`) and use that value for your `isMileageValid` variable.

Plus, in your example, you actually dont need `mileage` or `setMileage()` unless you use this somewhere else in the app.

```
const onChangeHandle = e => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  const isMileageValid = Number.isInteger(Number(val)) && Number(val) > 0;
  if (!isMileageValid){
    setErrorMessage(gettext('You must enter a valid mileage'));
  }
  else {
    setErrorMessage(null);
  }
  setMileage(val); // no longer needed because mileage isnt used
  setDisableConfirmButton(!isMileageValid);
}
```